# How to compile PNL(The Open Source Probabilistic Networks Library ) with vs2022？

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intel, bayesian, bayesian-networks

As far as I know, [PNL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openpnl/)(The Open Source Probabilistic Networks Library from Intel) has not been updated since 2005. At present, PNL source code can only be compiled through VC6.0. How to compile PNL with vs2022？

**Issue description update**:There are a lot of redefinition errors.Such as "error c2375 'pnl::pnlCombineNumericMatrices' redefinition different linkage".on line 56 of [pnliNumericSparseMatrix.hpp](https://github.com/cowboylym/OpenPNL/blob/master/c_pgmtk/src/include/pnliNumericSparseMatrix.hpp)

Comment: Did you try to compile it after loading the VC6 solution and allowing it to upgrade? What problems, if any, did you run into that you don't know how to fix? I have source code from a ton of games I worked on with VC6 and most compile with minor simple changes.

Comment: This may be a more up to date version: https://github.com/PyOpenPNL/OpenPNL

Comment: Thanks Reply. I can compile normally with VC6.0, but our current projects are developed with vs2017 or above, and the C++ standard and Windows toolchain used are much newer than VC6.0, so if I want to integrate PNL into In my project, it is necessary to use a high version of VS to develop. I tried to use vs2017 to upgrade the PNL project file. There is no problem with the upgrade itself, but many errors are reported in the compilation, and I can't solve it at present.

Comment: You should explain the process you've gone through to try and compile it with a newer version of Visual Studio and be specific about the errors you have that you do not know how to solve.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it first. I will ask you if I am unclear.

Comment: Don't delete and repost your old questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72403677/how-to-compile-pnlthe-open-source-probabilistic-networks-library-with-vs2022), especially not without changes; that's a big no-no.  It had only been up a couple days; probably not a very popular library.  Also, without showing any error messages from trying to build it with a newer compiler, there's nothing for people to look at & answer unless they actually use that library themselves.  I assume that's why people downvoted+closed the question before, and you haven't included any details.

Comment: It's also not clear what kind of answer this question could even have.  Like some compiler option that makes modern VS compatible with VS6.0?  Or you want people to fix the source code and post a patch as an answer? That sounds like a lot of work for a stack overflow question. If you don't understand what some specific compiler errors are about when you try to compile your source with a newer compiler, that would be something you could ask about, especially after reducing to a [mcve]. (But likely during that process you'll find an existing answer and not need to ask about that specific error).

Comment: Basically, "please port this old library to modern MSVC++ for me" isn't a good or on-topic Stack Overflow question.  And any other interpretation (like is there a newer version) is skirting pretty close to asking for library recommendations, which is a specific reason for closing questions as off-topic.  [ask] / https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  Not all questions are a good fit for Stack Overflow. I'm on the fence about this one; I think we allow questions about versions of some major programs, so it's maybe reasonable to ask if there's a working version, but hard to answer definite no

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I'll add more details later.

Comment: Anyway, definitely do not delete this and repost again.  Give it time for someone to notice this question about a niche library.  (Unless https://github.com/PyOpenPNL/OpenPNL already solves you problem.)  If you're in a rush, start working on porting it yourself, or hire someone, or try to drum up interest elsewhere, perhaps on the Intel forums if it's an Intel library.  Stack Overflow isn't a good place for recruiting collaborators for working on an open-source project.